# Facebook Email Extended Permissions Default Choice

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook Javascript API to request extended permissions for "email". It works and the user can choose between real and proxied email.

In my application, the default choice is the proxied email adress. I thought that was the default way for privacy reasons, but now my manager has seen this site: http://www.tripadvisor.com/ in which the default selection is the real email address instead of the proxied one and requested we implement the same.

What determines the default choice ? facebook, settings ? I haven't found anything official about this.

This is the code I'm using

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      // do some stuff
}, { perms: 'email' });
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook decides it. For newer and smaller apps the default seems to be proxied, but the official criteria are not public.