# Facebook test users and auth

Tags: facebook, email, testing, dialog, updates

I have a project where I am using Selenium to test the Facebook auth. I created a Facebook app, created a test user inside this app and created some tests using Facebook login. Until now, it was working. But during the last two weeks something changed in Facebook and my tests are failing. It is due to interface changes in permissions dialog (I am targeting the button by his id). The second problem is that I don't get the email address from Facebook test user but a proxy email which is longer than 75 characters (my db field length is hardcoded in framework I am using).

If I log in as a regular user, it is working correctly and I get this permission box:

[image]

But when I log in as the test user I created (via 'switch to' in app's developer roles), I get this box:

[image]

I tested it ~2 weeks ago and this was yet working. Today it is changed. So my questions:

- How to get back the old permissions box for test users?
- How can I get the real email address and not the proxy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with the Auth Dialog. I tried it with some old and new apps with various settings including March/Apr. 2013 Breaking Changes enabled/disabled, but it didn't help.
However, I guess I can help you with the email problem. When you login as a test user and go to account settings page, you will see the test user's primary email addres. By default this should be a really long one like the image I attached.

[image: default email address configuration for facebook test user]

Facebook Platform returns this [primary email address](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/). If you pass the Auth Dialog with your test user account and see [the privacy setting page](http://www.beta.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), you will find the default primary email address is shared with the app. You have to provide a new email address for the test user and set the new one as primary email address via [account setting page](https://www.beta.facebook.com/settings?tab=account).

Comment: Thanks for your effort Go. This is not much help as a) it's known and b) it can't be done programatically and mainly c) doesn't answer either of the posed questions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are changing the test user setting by hand and then auto-test the rest. 
If the email length is the problem, try specifying user name when creating test users via Graph API. Just specify name parameter, let's say "Vito Corleone", along with other parameters like permissions and locale and you'll get its email address like vito_XXXX_corleone@tfbnw.net. 
In my case it's usually 30-35 characters length depending on what comes for the XXXX part.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Try getting vito loggin in with vito to an app and getting his email through the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

### Why is the [Login Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) different with a test user?

With your test user, you can see the future of login dialogs. In fact, this isn't *"not working"* but this is an update which was unveiled on December 2012. Let me quote:

> Our Login dialogs have undergone a redesign to make it easier to
>   understand permissions that apps request. We've simplified
>   presentation and have also updated our language for greater clarity.
>
> “Basic info” has been renamed to “public profile and friend list,” to
>   reflect what what is being shared. Apps accessing your public profile
>   get your name, profile picture, age range, gender, language, country
>   and other public information.

Source: [Providing People Greater Clarity and Control, *developers.facebook.com/blog*](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/12/providing-people-greater-clarity-and-control/)

The reason why you don't meet this update with a regular user, is that Facebook doesn't use to update everyone at the same time. They partially launch updates depending on the country, the type of account or some other parameters I ignore.

**Example of a partial update ([unified_message FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message/)) dedicated to developer accounts:**

> We are providing early access to this API for registered developer
>   accounts only until the new messaging system is broadly available. You
>   should use the message table for production applications at the
>   current time.

In our case, we now know that test users can access to the update, but it is also said:

> We have already launched many of these improvements as part of our
>   iOS6 integration and are now rolling them out more broadly.

---

### About proxy emails

In fact, proxy emails are a way for any users to keep their real email anonymous. You *have* to consider proxy emails.

1. When joining an app, the user can choose between a real email and a proxy email: [image: Proxy email choice]
2. Other thing you need to expect are users **who didn't validate their account** when connecting to your app, a case which is possible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873298/fbconnect-returns-proxied-email-address) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630698/getting-user-information-email-specificlyy-before-he-verified-his-email/8631723#8631723).
3. Then, why do test users give back a proxy email? Because test users (being bots and having fake emails) **didn't validate their emails**.

You see that in at least 3 cases (and finally, test users are a good example), you need to handle these proxy emails. They are [incidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243213/1515819) or [accidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748892/facebook-return-proxy-email-instead-of-primary-email-starting-7-2-2013) met by developers and they can't be neglected. For your case, you can still try to disallow tests users who have a proxy email from accessing your app. But you *should* accept them and shouldn't force them to share their original e-mail addresses. A better solution is that you validate the test users emails:

1. Connect to the test user account that gives a proxy email
2. [Add an email address](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=email&view) (password needed here),
3. Go to the email mailbox and click on the validation link,
4. Set the new email address as primary,
5. The test user should now give his original email and not a proxy anymore!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I create testusers via API as part of my acceptance testing. The email in the response when creating is on the form  is a tfbnw.net-email. Logging into the account manually, this appears also to be the primary email. Via the javascript sdk I get the proxy however. So this part at least seems to be "not working". The time seems about right though, December, it stopped working around then. And only for test users. Regular users are fine. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you were using the API to create test users. I've updated my post with a possible solution.

Comment: That's almost what I'm doing. I'm not including either installed or true since that's part of the acceptance testing: to actually install the app and grant appropriate permissions. Length is not a problem.

Comment: Then may you explain what the real problem is? I actually thought having read: `The second problem is that I don't get the email address from Facebook test user but a proxy email which is longer than 75 characters `.

Comment: That is the problem for me, no emphasis on the length. The javascript sdk returns an email address ending in proxyemail.facebook.com, not tfbnw.net.

Comment: Oh ok! I simply didn't get what you meant by "proxy" emails. I just found at what they are and I updated my post according to my findings

Comment: I'm awarded you the bonus since time ran out and it seemed a shame to let the bonus go to waste and you really put in some effort. But it's frustrating that you still fail to grasp problem. I suggest you recreate the problem. 1. Create a test user through the API. 2. Use the email in the response to log on to facebook. 3. Log in to your app using the same email. 4. Check the email in your database. Length is not a problem. Real users are not the problem, only test users. The problem is that I get one email when creating the test user and another when adding the app.

Comment: And my answer is that this is not a *problem*. Why exactly do you complain of getting proxy emails? USERS give back a PROXY EMAIL when they didn't validate their original email, which IS the case of test users. You can set and validate specific emails to each of your test users if you don't want them to share a proxy. My post tries to make you understand that not only test users but **even** real users can use proxy emails and that this is not a malfunctioning behavior! What does it change to you? Why would you have the test users real email address if you know that they don't exist?

Comment: It may not be a problem for you but it is for me. Can you imagine no situation where confusion about users identified be email would be a problem? The tester is expecting Mary to log in and "Hello! Jonathan here!"

Comment: So, test users can't validate their emails. We're getting closer to the core of the problem. Yes, the problem. It wasn't a problem before. Again this came about only a couple of months ago. I understand your post about real users and their proxys. That's perfectly fine since they either registered their proxy email on my site or not at all. Real users are not a problem. Test users are. They cannot validate the address given at creation. They can change their email and validate that, but not programmatically via the API. That is a problem. It may not be for you, it wasn't for me but it is now.

Comment: Do you have a solution to mine Bruce's problem? If not, thank you for your time and effort and enjoy your bonus.

Comment: Is it a secret that is to say why it is more a problem for test users to give back a proxy email than for original users? I provided you a solution which cannot be done on the API. Things are presented how they are! You can't change Facebook so that all your desires become reality. Sorry! Btw, starting a bounty on SO doesn't mean that you'll predictably obtain the solution you dreamt. If there is no solution that fits your wishes, then let's say it: there is no solution for you and your post lead to nothing.

Comment: No it's not a secret, I believe the entire second last comment was about that, but most specifically the 6th sentence.
It would appear there is no solution.
It wasn't my post.